# specifying base_link frame for the Transformation tree

Tags: ros, transforms, base-link, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

The base_link frame of my robot is 16 cm above the ground (or base_footprint frame) and laser frame is 8 cm above the base_link frame and I have specified all the transformations with respect to base_link frame. The origin is set to the map frame. Here is my TF tree:

[image: image description]

Now my doubt is when I open RViz and see the robot_footprint with all the frames, base_link frame is on the ground and base_footprint is 16 cm below it, see the image:

[image: image description]

This causes laser to be 8 cm above the ground instead of 24 cm (16 cm + 8 cm) in RViz. Shouldn't the base_footprint be on the ground and base_link frame 16 cm above it? Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and how can I correct it so that the base_footprint is on the ground and base_link frame is 16 cm above it or am I misinterpreting something?

**Update:**
The odom_combined frame is also below the ground by 16 cm and is aligned with the base_footprint frame to start with:

[image: image description]

**Update 2:**
The output of `rosrun tf tf_echo map odom_combined` is :

```
At time 1435579139.606
- Translation: [2.414, 1.156, -0.160]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.003, 0.015, 0.680, 0.733]
            in RPY [0.016, 0.025, 1.496]
At time 1435579140.606
- Translation: [2.414, 1.156, -0.160]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.003, 0.015, 0.680, 0.733]
            in RPY [0.016, 0.025, 1.496]
```

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212177/specifying-base_link-frame-for-the-transformation-tree/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-06-27**:
There might be a problem with map->odom_combined tf. What is the output of `rosrun tf tf_echo map odom_combined`?

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-06-29**:
Thanks for the reply. I have updated my original question. Please have a look. TIA

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-06-29**:
So, 16 cm of difference in Z-direction is caused by that tf. `map->odom_combined` is provided by `amcl` node. I'm not experienced enough to pinpoint the error by looking at this information. I suspect there is something wrong with your amcl parameters. Maybe you should share your launch file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I figured out the problem. The `base_frame_id` in the amcl launch file should be base_footprint and not base_link. In my amcl.launch file,  I changed `<param name="base_frame_id" value="base_link"/>` to  `<param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>` and now the transformations look correct. Thanks a lot to @yigit for helping me out.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-06-29**:
Sure. I'm glad I could help.